# Standard Deviation of Ratios/Indices?

Tags: standard-deviation, error, sample, ratio

Just wanted to hear some thoughts on whether we can calculate standard deviation for observations that are actually disparity indices obtained for each racial group (e.g. White, Black, etc.) separately.

So, basically, a population of students was surveyed and representation of each racial group was assessed in a particular group. Some are overrepresented some are underrepresented.

The conclusion is based on what proportion they account for in the overall population vs. the specific program. The ratios are - below 1=underrepresentation, above 1=overrepresentation. I want to establish thresholds now and wanted to do it via standard deviations from them mean of these ratios.

My question - is that a valid approach?

Comment: What are the thresholds intended to represent or accomplish?

Comment: They indicate no-disproportionality, mild, moderate and severe:                            
Group A  0.88 
Group B  1.06 
Group C  0.85 
Group D  0.92 
Group E  0.89 
Group B  1.06 
Group A  1.00 
Group B  1.03 
Group A  1.02 We need to decide where the cutoff are

Comment: In your post I cannot discern any information that would enable anyone to relate standard deviations to "no-disproportionality:" the former are a statistical property of data while the latter are some kind of social model construct.